# ReactMapGl clicking on specified layer not possible

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I've got a map style set up in Mapbox Studio. This style contains a layer with markers. I want to be able to click on this layer in my React project using react-map-gl.

In any other situation i would do something like

`map.on('click', 'needed-layer', () => {this.dostuff()});`

This does not seem to work in ReactMapGL.

I made a reference to the map like so:

```
<ReactMapGL
   ref={this.mapRef}
   ...
 />

this.mapRef = React.createRef();
this.map = this.mapRef.current.getMap();
```

If I log this.map i get a Map object which is good, but I would think the following code would detect a click on the predefined layer:

```
this.map.on('click', 'needed-layer', () => {this.dostuff()});
```

but it doesn't. Any ideas on how to click on a marker layer predefined in Mapbox Studio?

Comment: Hey! Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is an **onClick event** which comes under the default `Map` (former `ReactMapGL` / `MapGL`) component.

You will need to specify the `interactiveLayerIds` property to make it work on specific layers.

Please refer to the section of [onClick event](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/map#onclick) from the most recent `react-map-gl` documentation.